# How to install mahout using ambari server

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, mahout, hortonworks-data-platform

I have created a hadoop cluster using 3 slaves and 1 master using ambari server(hortonworks). I need to install mahout 0.9 in the master machine in order to run mahout jobs in the cluster. How do I do that?

I am using ambari 1.5.1 and HDP 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello fellow Hortonworker!  Mahout is in the HDP repositories, but it's not available in the ambari install wizard (i.e. Services->Add Service).  Therefore the only way to install it is via:

```
yum install mahout
```

As noted [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap-mahout.html), you should only install it on the master node.  Also note that Mahout is a *library* not a *service*.  There is nothing for ambari to monitor in terms of additional services to be run on nodes.  If you are using maven to manage your build dependencies, you can just add the following to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  Install it however you would install any other java library.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Mahout 0.9.0.2.3 has been made available in the Ambari Install Wizard. [image]